# How to dynamically import a component in React?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, lazy-loading, dynamic-import

I am trying to optimize a component of mine with dynamic rendering, but I'm facing some issues, so this is my current situation:

I have an `Alert` component that renders an alert message, along with an icon.

I have a `Icons` module, which is a library of icons

I am currently rendering the icon as follows (this is not actual code, it's just to give the idea):

```
import * as icons from '../icons';
import DefaultIcon from '../icons';

function Alert(iconName='defaultIcon', message) {  

  function getIcon(iconName) {
    if (iconName === 'defaultIcon') {
      return DefaultIcon()
    }
    return icons[iconName]
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <span>{getIcon(iconName)}</span>
      <span>{message}</span>
    </div>

  )
}
```

So, suppose `Alert` gets called without `iconName` most of the times, so the components doesn't need to import all of the icons at all.

I would like to avoid including all of the icons in the `Alert` component by default, but only doing so if `iconName` is specified

Is it even possible to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, looks like I managed, and that's how I did it:

```
import DefaultIcon from '../icons';

function Alert(message, iconName="") {
  const [icon, useIcon] = useState();

  //componentDidMount
  const useEffect(() => {
    //if an icon name is specified, import the icons
    if (iconName) {
      import("./icons").then(icons => setIcon(icons[iconName]))
    } else {
      setIcon(DefaultIcon)
    }
  }
  ,[])
  
  return (
    <span>{icon}</span>
    <span>{message}</span>
  )
}
```

Comment: why "const useEffect" ?

Comment: silly mistake, ignore that const

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible this way.

Maybe create a component for the Icon that imports the icon libary. In the Alert component you could implement the Icon component as a child:

```
<Alert message="Alert!">
  <Icon iconName="defaultIcon" />
</Alert>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should import icons dynamically with type or name etc. something like below.

```
import React from 'react';

export default function Icon({ type, ...props }) {
  const Icon = require(`./icons/${type}`).default;

  return <Icon {...props} />
}

import Icon from './Icon';

<Icon type="addIcon" />
```