# How to dynamically import a MDX Component in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mdxjs

I created an Article component which gets its title through the route parameters like this:

```
const Article = () => {
  const params = useParams()
  const dashedTitle = params.title.replace(/ /g, '-')
  
  return (
    <article>
      <MyMDX />
    </article>
  );
}
```

I want to return a MDX file with the same name as the provided title. Simply returning the `<MyMDX />` component works fine if I manually import it at the top of the article with `import MyMDX from '../markdowns/mymdx.mdx`. However, I don't see a way to import this file dynamically, depending on the tile.

Is there a way to do this or could I do this in a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a solution to this:

```
const Article = () => {
    
    const params = useParams()
    const [article, setArticle] = useState()

    dashedTitle = params.title.replace(/ /g, '-')

    useEffect(() => {
        import(`../markdowns/${dashedTitle}.mdx`).then(module => {
            setArticle(module.default)
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
            setArticle(undefined)
        })
    }, [dashedTitle])

    return (
        <article>
            {article ? article : <NotFound />}
        </article>
    );
}
```

With useEffect, import the MDX module and then set my article variable to the module's default export (which is exactly the generated JSX component). Thus, I can use it in the return segment in case it's not undefined.

Additionally, I found a [similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67707793/10736168) that could help.